# How to convert date in the form 2013-02-27 00:00:00 so I can use it with ORDER BY?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-order-by

So I'd like to add `ORDER BY` in my query but it's not working because the date field is in the form `2013-02-27 00:00:00`. How do I convert it on the fly so that I can use it with `ORDER BY`? Here's my query:

```
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts"; 
    $sql .= " INNER JOIN $wpdb->postmeta ON $wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->postmeta.post_id";
    $sql .= " WHERE $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'task'";
    $sql .= " AND $wpdb->postmeta.post_id IN ( SELECT `post_id` FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE $wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = '_completed' AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value = '0' )";
    $sql .= " AND $wpdb->postmeta.post_id IN ( SELECT `post_id` FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE $wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = '_assigned' AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value = '%s' )";
    $sql .= " GROUP BY $wpdb->postmeta.post_id";
    $sql .= " ORDER BY $wpdb->postmeta._due ASC";

    $tasks = $wpdb->get_results( sprintf( $sql, $user_id ) );
```

The field in question is `_due` in table `wp_postmeta`. This is for Wordpress but since it's a MYSQL question I thought I'd ask it here. Thanks!

Comment: That's exactly the format you want for date sorting. What isn't working that you're asking this question?

Comment: @John Conde It's not working because it can't recognize the format in the field? I don't know but it's not working if I use that field with `ORDER BY`.

Comment: Are your `$wpdb->XXX` variables being substituted into `$sql`? Don't you need to put `{}` around them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you're using a `GROUP BY` (incorrectly) and MySQL does not guarantee the order of the sort. If you use the functionality correctly, you'll get the desired result.

See [MySQL Extensions to `GROUP BY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-extensions.html).